# Cor dinâmica em TextField em relatórios Jasper

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

Quero mudar a cor do textfield de acordo com o valor do mesmo,
achei vários tutoriais que dizem pra criar um style e aplicar ao textfield, tem que marcar uma opção "styled text" que não encontrei nas propriedades do textfield no jasper, os tutoriais todos referem-se ao Ireport e eu uso o JasperReports, alguma dica?

Comment: Olá Julio, você poderia postar um [mvce](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) com um relatório de exemplo, a chamada para gerá-lo e o ponto em que você deseja aplicar o estilo dinamicamente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caso não encontre, outra possível solução é sobrepor outro textfield com a cor que quer e faz o chaveamento para mostrar um ou outro :)

Comment: É, não queria usar esta mais vai ser o jeito! Kkkkkkkkkkkk Valeu cara!

Answer (score 1):

Eu ja passei por esse mesmo problema, eu precisava pintar cada linha do par do relatorio de vermelho, então achei seguinte a solução:

```
<style name="style_fundo_vermelho" mode="Opaque">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue() %2 == 0)]]></conditionExpression>
            <style backcolor="#FF0000"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
```

aqui nesse trecho eu crio o Style que tem uma condição booleana:

*(se o numero do contador da linha dividido por 2 for = 0 então ele é uma linha par e seu fundo vai ser vermelho)*

```
new Boolean($V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue() %2 == 0)
```

após criar esse style com o nome= **style_fundo_vermelho** eu adiciono ele ao atributo style do textField:

```
<textField>
    <reportElement style="style_fundo_vermelho" x="658" y="1" width="90" height="16" uuid="c118ccc6-4074-4f03-9bfa-cf6c3ae8a1b9">
    </reportElement>    
</textField>
```

Assim você já pode resolver seu problema de cor de fundo dinâmica no text field, basta adaptar a  do style para a sua necessidade.